# Network Access and Download File

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I am working on a simple program to access web (weather.noaa.gov) and download a text file. Following is my code. I get a message "network has stopped working". I have added the INTERNET permissions in Manifest file.  I appreciate your help. Thanks, Sam

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //mTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final Button loadButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.load_button);

    loadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            new HttpGetTask().execute();
            //enterClicked();
          }
    });

}


private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    //private static final String TAG ="HttpGetTask";
    private static final String URL="http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/KORD.TXT";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...params){
        String data=null;
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;

        try {
            httpUrlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL).openConnection();

            InputStream in =new BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

            data = readStream(in);
             } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
         return data;


        }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        mTextView.setText(result);
    }


    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    //private void readStream(InputStream in) {
          BufferedReader reader = null;
          StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //data += line +"\n";
                data.append(line);
                //System.out.println(line);
            }
          }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
              try {
                reader.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

       }
    return data.toString();
   }

  }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you also need the permitions to write to disk

Comment: @jycr753,  Thanks,  I am only looking to display the file content using mTextView.  it seems like my title is bit misleading. sorry for the confusion. Sam

Comment: The message you see on the screen is useless.  You need to use logcat and capture a stack trace.

Comment: I solved the problem. Error was that the mTextView  not given a id